# Anyone have a solution how to save datagridview data to mysql and retrive it (with aes_encrypt/decrypt)

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

this code is that what i have now and it works but i become always this message. the image is in german sorry for that 
google translated:

the object reference was not set to an object instance

the problem comes when i click the Populate function
(in visualstudio is no errormessage only in the tool)

thank you guys

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmObv.png)

```
private void Add(string Kundenname, string Game, string Bezahlung, string Bezahlt, string Erledigt, string PayPalEmail, string ACCEmail, string ACCPW)
    {
        //SQL STMT
        string sql = "INSERT INTO kunden(Kundenname,Game,Bezahlung,Bezahlt,Erledigt,PayPalEmail,ACCEmail,ACCPW) VALUES(@KUNDENNAME,@GAME,@BEZAHLUNG" +
            ",@BEZAHLT,@ERLEDIGT,@PAYPALEMAIL,@ACCEMAIL,@ACCPW)";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        //ADD PARAMETERS
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KUNDENNAME", Kundenname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GAME", Game);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEZAHLUNG", Bezahlung);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEZAHLT", Bezahlt);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ERLEDIGT", Erledigt);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PAYPALEMAIL", PayPalEmail);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCEMAIL", ACCEmail);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ACCPW", Encrypt(ACCPW));
        //OPEN CON AND EXEC insert
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                ClearTxts();
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully Inserted");
            }
            con.Close();
            Retrieve();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Populate(String ID, string Kundenname, string Game, string Bezahlung, string Bezahlt, string Erledigt, string PayPalEmail, string ACCEmail, string ACCPW)
    {
        dgv.Rows.Add(ID, Kundenname, Game, Bezahlung, Bezahlt, Erledigt, PayPalEmail, ACCEmail, ACCPW);
    }
    //RETRIEVE FROM DB
    private void Retrieve()
    {
        dgv.Rows.Clear();
        //SQL STMT
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM kunden ";
        cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
        //OPEN CON,RETRIEVE,FILL DGVIEW
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            //LOOP THRU DT
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)

            {
                    Populate(row[0].ToString(), row[1].ToString(), row[2].ToString(), row[3].ToString(), row[4].ToString(), row[5].ToString(), row[6].ToString(), row[7].ToString(), row[8].ToString());
                foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dgv.Rows)
                {
                     rows.Cells[8].Value = Decrypt(rows.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                }
            }
                con.Close();
                //CLEAR DT
                dt.Rows.Clear();
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: which line are you having the error?

Comment: Yet another [common ordinary NullReference Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/26761773#26761773) even if it is a link to a picture of an error in German  Read [ask] and take the [tour], please

Comment: When i comment this out the error isnt there.                 foreach (DataGridViewRow rows in dgv.Rows)
                {
                     rows.Cells[8].Value = Decrypt(rows.Cells[8].Value.ToString());
                }

Comment: @Plutonix i translated the german picture in english see above

Comment: fixed this error!
please close